# Last minute car renting at San Diego Airport

Tags: car-rentals, san-diego

I was planning to rely on Uber, but realised that renting a car might be worthwhile. I am traveling today and all car rental websites I know only provide rentals in 3-4 days from now.

Is my only solution to check on arrival, or can I still check options online for car rentals today? I don't have phone access, but I do have some flight connections, where I will have some time to search for options.

So my question boils down to, can I book a car online today at San Diego airport?

Answer (score 3):

There's no rule against it.

A quick search on hertz.com revealed plenty of options left for today.

I would try to secure it online rather than at the desk.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, should be no problem. Here's [a list](http://www.san.org/Parking-Transportation/Rental-Cars) of all the car rental companies operating near the SD airport (from the San Diego Airport website).

I had no problem finding a small car at Dollar for 3:30 today at ~$50/day.